# Authorize all users that don't have a role assigned in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way in MVC C# to allow users that don't have a role assigned yet.

For example

```
[Authorize(Roles="a, b, c, d")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles="")
    public ActionResult ChooseYourRole() 
    //I want only authenticated users with no roles assigned to access this action
    {
    }
    ....other actions....
}
```

Comment: Just have another controller... You don't need to shove everything into a single controller. That's bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Authorization Attribute to achieve this

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private bool allowUserWithNoRole = false;
    public MyAuthorizationAttribute (bool AllowUserWithNoRole) : base()
    {
        this.allowUserWithNoRole = allowUserWithNoRole;
    }
}
```

In your AuthorizeCore perform your required check which is roles == 0

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
       return false;

    if (allowUserWithNoRole && Roles.Count() == 0) 
    {
        return true;                
    } 
    else {
       //Perform additional checks for authorization
    }
}
```

I have also added a field called allowUserWithNoRole. This will take care of instances where you want a different behaviour for your Authorization when Roles is left empty.

Finally, you set this custom attribute above your Action

```
[MyAuthorization(AllowUserWithNoRole=true, Roles="")
public ActionResult ChooseYourRole() 
//I want only authenticated users with no roles assigned to access this action
{
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but in the Action you're still using the Authorize attribute, not the custom attribute. You need to fix that.

Comment: You're welcome. But, you don't need the `Roles = ""`, do you?